# How to view all good posts (on this site)

Tags: discussion, search

Disclaimer: This ***might*** belong on [LifeHacks Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/)

I just went through every page/post on this site (about 1300 posts) over the past week-ish, looking for gems of knowledge.

Sure, I found some good ones, plenty of bad ones, and a rare few life-changing ones.

Is there a better way to browse forums for quality posts? (especially StackExchange forums).

PS - I'm open to using advanced search techniques, I just don't know any.

Comment: You can see different sections under questions, click sort by votes

Comment: @JustDoIt But what if it's new? or Just hasn't gotten a lot of attention?

Comment: Questions can be seen as good or bad postings depending on how the community receives them. If they're good they're usually going to get views, upvotes and hopefully shares.

Comment: You can check the most popular posts by going to the Questions tab and sorting by votes.

Comment: There is also a tab for hot questions, which would help for the newest questions. I don't know about unpopular questions, though.